# Can Windows Live Writer 2011 be configured to accept self-signed SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-live-writer

I'd like to use Windows Live Writer 2011 with a blog that is configured to use self-signed SSL certificates. Unfortunately when connecting to the blog Windows Live Writer 2010 refuses to connect to such an "insecure" server. There is no option to "connect anyway".

Is there a configuration in the registry or somewhere else that would let me connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows list of "trusted" certificates can be managed directly by using `certmgr.msc`. You can start this from the Run menu under the start button. If you add your certificate  under 3rd party certs, your certificate will now be considered signed by a trusted source.

Comment: This is where its at.  Live Writer doesn't make the connection. Windows does.